# iOS 7’s Notes app paper texture/background

Tags: iphone, ios7, psd

Does anyone know where I can get a raw version of the Notes paper background? Preferably in PSD format?

In the past I’ve used a screenshot from my iPhone, however, now there’s an @3x version (and I have the 5s) the quality may be affected. I’ve tried making them myself in Photoshop but it’s nowhere near as good.

Alternatively, if anyone has an iPhone 6 or above and can send me an @3x version of the Notes background, it’d be much appreciated!

Thanks as always

Comment: Did you try grabbing it from the Notes app bundle?

Comment: I didn’t even know I could access the Notes.app - can you provide instructions please?

Comment: http://dl.i-funbox.com/

Comment: Just downloaded iFunBox. Only user applications are there, no Apple apps

Comment: Oh, I guess then it requires a jailbroken device.

Comment: If you have access to it, would you mind sending me the images?

Comment: Sorry don't have a jailbroken iOS device.

Answer (score 5):

Here You Go! The Paper backgrounds from iOS Notes App.

[image: iOS Note app "Paper" Background]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just get it from the macOS Notes app! Just go to it in Finder, right-click, then click "show package contents." Now go to the "resources" folder. The background image might be there!